# Creating a php calculator

Tags: php, html

This is what I have typed. For this form method I want to get the answer in the answer input field. 
The php is not working. I can't understand what's wrong

```php
  <form action="index.html" method="get">
       <h1>Calculator</h1>
       <a>Num 1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="num1" value=""><br><br>
       <a>Num 2</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="num2" value=""><br><br>
       <a>Answer</a>&nbsp; <input type="text" name="ans" value=""><br><br>
       <button type="button" name="add">+</button>
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <button type="button" name="subtract">-</button>
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <button type="button" name="multiply">*</button>
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <button type="button" name="devide">/</button>
     </form>

<?php
if (isset($_GET["add"]) == 'add') {
  $number1 = $_GET['num1'];
  $number2 = $_GET['num2'];
  $answer = $_GET['ans'];

  $_GET['ans'] = $_GET['num1'] + $_GET['num2'];
  $_GET['ans'];
 }
```

?>

Comment: It is just Html .. where is your PHP code ..

Comment: `isset($_GET["add"])` returns a boolean, and it never equals to `add`. Also `$_GET['ans'];` itself does nothing, you might want to print it to screen.

Answer (score 1):

First thing wrong is this line:

```
if (isset($_GET["add"]) == 'add') {
```

`isset()` returns true or false, so while you could compare it with `add` and it will result in `true` overall, it doesn't make any sense.

You can make it a lot easier by giving all buttons the same name and different values:

```
<button type="submit" name="action" value="add">+</button>
<button type="submit" name="action" value="subtract">-</button>
<button type="submit" name="action" value="multiply">*</button>
<button type="submit" name="action" value="divide">/</button>
```

Note that I also changed the `type` to `submit`, a type `button` will NOT submit your form!
Also, change the `action="index.html"` to `action="index.php"`, a `.html` file will not execute any PHP code at all.

Now you can select your operation with a simple switch:

```
switch ($_GET['action']) {
    case 'add':
        $answer = $_GET['num1'] + $_GET['num2'];
        break;
    case 'subtract':
        // your substract code
        break;
    case 'multiply':
        // your multiply code
        break;
    case 'divide':
        // your divide code
        break;      
}
```

Last, but not least, you calculate this after the HTML has already been printed. You can't just write back to `$_GET` and expect the already printed HTML field to change. So, place the PHP in front and output the result in the input field:

```
<?php
if ( isset($_GET['action']) ) {
    switch ($_GET['action']) {
        case 'add':
            $answer = $_GET['num1'] + $_GET['num2'];
            break;
        case 'subtract':
            // your substract code
            break;
        case 'multiply':
            // your multiply code
            break;
        case 'divide':
            // your divide code
            break;      
    }
}
?>

<form action="index.php" method="get">
    Num 1 <input type="text" name="num1"><br><br>
    Num 2 <input type="text" name="num2"><br><br>
    Answer <input type="text" name="ans" value="<?php echo $answer; ?>"><br><br>

    <button type="submit" name="action" value="add">+</button>
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="subtract">-</button>
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="multiply">*</button>
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="divide">/</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make your button type="submit"

Answer (score 0):

Check this, I didnt tested it.

**Solution 1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="#">

Enter the First Number <input type="text" name="number1"> <br><br>

Enter the Second Number <input type="text" name="number2"><br><br>

Choose the operation 

Addition <input type="radio" name="op" value="add" checked>

Subtraction <input type="radio" name="op" value="sub">

Multiplication <input type="radio" name="op" value="mul">

Division<input type="radio" name="op" value="div"><br><br>

 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

if ( $op == "add" ) {
  echo "$number1 + $number2 = ";
  echo $number1 + $number2;
}

if ( $op == "sub" ) {
  echo "$number1 - $number2 = ";
  echo $number1 - $number2;
}

if ( $op == "mul" ) {
  echo "$number1 * $number2 = ";
  echo $number1 * $number2;
}

if ( $op == "div" ) {
  echo "$number1 / $number2 = ";
  echo $number1 / $number2;
}

?>
```

**Solution 2**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple PHP Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="#">
        <input type="text" name="value1">
        <input type="text" name="value2">
        <select name="action">
            <option>+</option>
            <option>-</option>
            <option>*</option>
            <option>/</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate Now'">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $value1 = $_POST["value1"];
    $value2 = $_POST["value2"];
    $action = $_POST["action"];

if($action==”+”)
    {
    echo "<b>Addition : - </b>" . ($value1+$value2) . "\n\n";
    }

if($action==”-“)
    {
    echo "<b>Subtraction : -</b>" . ($value1-$value2). "\n\n";
    }

if($action==”*”)
    {
    echo "<b>Multiplication : -</b>" . ($value1*$value2). "\n\n";
    }

if($action==”/”)
    {
    echo "<b>Division : - </b>" . ($value1)/($value2) . "\n\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I just updated my question with the php code i tried. Please check it.

Comment: Hey I have updated my answer. Please have a look. If you still get nay problem let me know . Sometime little things are difficult

Comment: Please do _always_ sanitize user input!

Comment: Okay Paul.  I tried as per the input also.  But it not worked after spending too much time on that. So provide solution as per my way.